# How to count instances of integers including zero values in r

Tags: r

I have a list of integers that are all between 1 and 365. There are some integers that appear multiple times and some that do not appear. I would like to use a function like count to have a dataframe that counts the number of occurrences it appears including if it does not appear.

```
df
x  freq
1  0
2  1
3  3
4  0
```

Currently, both the rows for 1 and 4 do not exist in my current count function `df=count(list)`

Comment: Try the `table` command.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `factor` with `levels` specified so that it will also take care of the missing elements and report the count as 0

```
table(factor(df$x, levels = 1:4))
```